# composer will no longer update

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Here is my composer.json:

```
    {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
                "greggilbert/recaptcha": "dev-master",
                "way/generators": "~2.0"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ],
                "psr-0": {
                    "MSHLibrary": "app/"
                }
        },
        "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "require-dev": {
                "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"
        }
}
```

However when I run composer update (yes I have run composer self-update) I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Installation request for greggilbert/recaptcha dev-master -> satisfiable by greggilbert/recaptcha[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - greggilbert/recaptcha dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.4].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be getting the dev-master version of [greggilbert/recaptcha](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha), but according to its [README](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha/blob/master/README.md), it's only to be used for Laravel 5 projects.

To fix this, try 1.* releases instead; they're suited for Laravel 4:

```
"greggilbert/recaptcha": "1.*",
```

Comment: Good answer. This is why `dev-master` requirements aren't much fun long-term.

Comment: This is in fact the issue. Thanks!